# Changing the Ubuntu 13.10 Ambiance Colours

Tags: themes, colors, ambiance

In previous versions of Ubuntu (including Ubuntu 13.04) I was able to change the system ambiance colour from orange to a colour of my liking by using this in the terminal:

```
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-color-scheme "selected_bg_color:#33B5E5;selected_fg_color:#FFFFFF"
```

This would ultimately change the orange ambiance colour to #3385E5 which is a blue colour.

Does anyone know how I can go about changing it once again in Ubuntu 13.10?

Comment: I'd like to try this in my 13.04, but first, how can I undo it if I don't like it?

Answer (score 1):

doug's answer is good but it's overkill.  You can actually copy /usr/share/themes/Ambiance into your ~/.themes directory and then edit Ambiance just for your user.

Answer (score 1):

My answer from [Theme color conversion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400102/theme-color-conversion)

A useful tool I use to customize gtk theme is gtk-theme-config. I for example like the default ambiance them but I set it to use a green scheme so it looks better with the gnome colors icon theme.

You can see here the greybird gtk theme wich has a blue scheme by default turned to purple and the gtk theme config at the bottom right corner.

[image]

Greybird gtk them wich has a blue scheme by default.

For install it in Saucy:

sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config

For previous ubuntu releases:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html

**P.S.** If you feel like it should be marked as duplicate, please go on.

Comment: Very good tool. It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

That gsetting will now only affect a couple of areas, to get 'full coverage' you'll need to directly edit some files in  `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0`

make your changes in `settings.ini` & `gtk-main.css` (maybe only one is needed, I do both

Also doesn't hurt to make same changes in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` though likely not needed if you've run the gsetting command