# Theme color conversion

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Simple question. I like the [Ambiance-dark](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+Dark?content=147513) theme found online, but I heavily dislike orange. I went in the theme files and modified the colour settings to green, but there is one little thing that I can't seem to find how to change: the separators for dropdown menu and tools. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, these are pink (or light orange if you prefer). How do I change those colours?

Now, I *haven't yet changed the hue of all the assets of the theme* (only the close button, which can be seen on screenshot. I'd like to know if these colours (menu/tool separators) are assets dependant.

Thanks!

Comment: Pastebin the file you are editing, otherwise people will need to download the files to look at them.

Answer (score 0):

A useful tool I use to customize gtk theme is **gtk-theme-config**. I for example like the default ambiance them but I set it to use a green scheme so it looks better with the gnome colors icon theme.

You can see here the greybird gtk theme wich has a blue scheme by default turned to purple and the gtk theme config at the bottom right corner.

[image: Greybird gtk them wich has a blue scheme by default.]

For install it in Saucy:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```

For previous ubuntu releases:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shimmerproject/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-config
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/customize-gtk3-gtk2-theme-colors-using.html